# Repack existing boot.img using mkbootimg (cyanogenmod 12.1, lollipop)

Tags: android

This is a cross-post from [xda-developers](http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-note-2/devs-only/repack-cm12-1-boot-img-using-mkbootimg-t3089815), hopefully someone here knows the solution. I have trouble re-packing existing boot.img from CyanogenMod 12.1 (Lollipop 5.1) for d2spr (Sprint S3). Resulting image will not boot. I built mkbootimg/unpackbootimg from source found here: https://github.com/osm0sis/mkbootimg . Then I do following:

```
$ mkdir boot2
$ ../unpackbootimg -i boot.img -o boot2
BOARD_KERNEL_CMDLINE androidboot.hardware=qcom user_debug=31 zcache androidboot.bootdevice=msm_sdcc.1
BOARD_KERNEL_BASE 80200000
BOARD_NAME 
BOARD_PAGE_SIZE 2048
BOARD_KERNEL_OFFSET 00008000
BOARD_RAMDISK_OFFSET 01500000
BOARD_TAGS_OFFSET 00000100
```

This unpacks boot.img into:

```
$ ls -l boot2
total 7360
-rw-rw---- 1 galets galets       9 Apr 22 08:59 boot.img-base
-rw-rw---- 1 galets galets       1 Apr 22 08:59 boot.img-board
-rw-rw---- 1 galets galets      81 Apr 22 08:59 boot.img-cmdline
-rw-rw---- 1 galets galets       9 Apr 22 08:59 boot.img-kerneloff
-rw-rw---- 1 galets galets       5 Apr 22 08:59 boot.img-pagesize
-rw-rw---- 1 galets galets  663238 Apr 22 08:59 boot.img-ramdisk.gz
-rw-rw---- 1 galets galets       9 Apr 22 08:59 boot.img-ramdiskoff
-rw-rw---- 1 galets galets       9 Apr 22 08:59 boot.img-tagsoff
-rw-rw---- 1 galets galets 6842760 Apr 22 08:59 boot.img-zImage
```

Then I repackage files without any modification:

```
$ ../mkbootimg --kernel boot2/boot.img-zImage \
>              --ramdisk boot2/boot.img-ramdisk.gz \
>              --cmdline "androidboot.hardware=qcom user_debug=31 zcache androidboot.bootdevice=msm_sdcc.1" \
>              --base 0x80200000 \
>              --pagesize 2048 \
>              --output boot2.img
$ ../boot_info boot2.img 
Page size: 2048 (0x00000800)
Kernel size: 6842760 (0x00686988)
Ramdisk size: 663238 (0x000a1ec6)
Second size: 0 (0x00000000)
Board name: 
Command line: 'androidboot.hardware=qcom user_debug=31 zcache androidboot.bootdevice=msm_sdcc.1'
Base address: 2149580800 (0x80200000)
```

For comparison, original boot:

```
$ ../boot_info boot.img 
Page size: 2048 (0x00000800)
Kernel size: 6842760 (0x00686988)
Ramdisk size: 663238 (0x000a1ec6)
Second size: 0 (0x00000000)
Board name: 
Command line: 'androidboot.hardware=qcom user_debug=31 zcache androidboot.bootdevice=msm_sdcc.1'
Base address: 2149580800 (0x80200000)
```

All seems fine. Then I flash it:

```
$ heimdall flash --BOOT boot2.img 
Heimdall v1.4.0

Copyright (c) 2010-2013, Benjamin Dobell, Glass Echidna
http://www.glassechidna.com.au/

This software is provided free of charge. Copying and redistribution is
encouraged.

If you appreciate this software and you would like to support future
development please consider donating:
http://www.glassechidna.com.au/donate/

Initialising connection...
Detecting device...
Claiming interface...
Attempt failed. Detaching driver...
Claiming interface again...
Setting up interface...

Initialising protocol...
Protocol initialisation successful.

Beginning session...

Some devices may take up to 2 minutes to respond.
Please be patient!

Session begun.

Downloading device's PIT file...
PIT file download successful.

Uploading BOOT
100%
BOOT upload successful

Ending session...
Rebooting device...
Releasing device interface...
Re-attaching kernel driver...
```

and device won't boot. Help!

**EDIT**: Here's a hex dump of beginning of two images:

```
$ hexdump -C boot.img | more
00000000  41 4e 44 52 4f 49 44 21  88 69 68 00 00 80 20 80  |ANDROID!.ih... .|
00000010  c6 1e 0a 00 00 00 70 81  00 00 00 00 00 00 10 81  |......p.........|
00000020  00 01 20 80 00 08 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |.. .............|
00000030  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000040  61 6e 64 72 6f 69 64 62  6f 6f 74 2e 68 61 72 64  |androidboot.hard|
00000050  77 61 72 65 3d 71 63 6f  6d 20 75 73 65 72 5f 64  |ware=qcom user_d|
00000060  65 62 75 67 3d 33 31 20  7a 63 61 63 68 65 20 61  |ebug=31 zcache a|
00000070  6e 64 72 6f 69 64 62 6f  6f 74 2e 62 6f 6f 74 64  |ndroidboot.bootd|
00000080  65 76 69 63 65 3d 6d 73  6d 5f 73 64 63 63 2e 31  |evice=msm_sdcc.1|
00000090  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
00000240  bc 67 a2 74 d6 d0 01 0e  b4 56 47 6f bd ad 4d 85  |.g.t.....VGo..M.|
00000250  30 c1 ee 43 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |0..C............|
00000260  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
00000800  00 00 a0 e1 00 00 a0 e1  00 00 a0 e1 00 00 a0 e1  |................|
*
00000820  02 00 00 ea 18 28 6f 01  00 00 00 00 88 69 68 00  |.....(o......ih.|
00000830  01 70 a0 e1 00 00 30 e3  00 80 a0 11 02 80 a0 01  |.p....0.........|
00000840  20 30 9f e5 00 00 93 e5  1c 10 9f e5 01 00 30 e1  | 0............0.|
00000850  06 00 00 1a 00 00 a0 e3  00 00 83 e5 0c 00 93 e5  |................|
00000860  08 10 93 e5 04 f0 93 e5  00 f0 ff ff 07 b0 5d 4a  |..............]J|
00000870  00 20 0f e1 03 00 12 e3  01 00 00 1a 17 00 a0 e3  |. ..............|
00000880  56 34 12 ef 00 20 0f e1  c0 20 82 e3 02 f0 21 e1  |V4... ... ....!.|
00000890  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000008a0  5c 41 9f e5 65 00 00 eb  57 0f 8f e2 4e 1c 90 e8  |\A..e...W...N...|


$ hexdump -C boot2.img | more
00000000  41 4e 44 52 4f 49 44 21  88 69 68 00 00 80 20 80  |ANDROID!.ih... .|
00000010  c6 1e 0a 00 00 00 20 81  00 00 00 00 00 00 10 81  |...... .........|
00000020  00 01 20 80 00 08 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |.. .............|
00000030  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000040  61 6e 64 72 6f 69 64 62  6f 6f 74 2e 68 61 72 64  |androidboot.hard|
00000050  77 61 72 65 3d 71 63 6f  6d 20 75 73 65 72 5f 64  |ware=qcom user_d|
00000060  65 62 75 67 3d 33 31 20  7a 63 61 63 68 65 20 61  |ebug=31 zcache a|
00000070  6e 64 72 6f 69 64 62 6f  6f 74 2e 62 6f 6f 74 64  |ndroidboot.bootd|
00000080  65 76 69 63 65 3d 6d 73  6d 5f 73 64 63 63 2e 31  |evice=msm_sdcc.1|
00000090  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
00000240  bc 67 a2 74 d6 d0 01 0e  b4 56 47 6f bd ad 4d 85  |.g.t.....VGo..M.|
00000250  30 c1 ee 43 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |0..C............|
00000260  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
00000800  00 00 a0 e1 00 00 a0 e1  00 00 a0 e1 00 00 a0 e1  |................|
*
00000820  02 00 00 ea 18 28 6f 01  00 00 00 00 88 69 68 00  |.....(o......ih.|
00000830  01 70 a0 e1 00 00 30 e3  00 80 a0 11 02 80 a0 01  |.p....0.........|
00000840  20 30 9f e5 00 00 93 e5  1c 10 9f e5 01 00 30 e1  | 0............0.|
00000850  06 00 00 1a 00 00 a0 e3  00 00 83 e5 0c 00 93 e5  |................|
00000860  08 10 93 e5 04 f0 93 e5  00 f0 ff ff 07 b0 5d 4a  |..............]J|
00000870  00 20 0f e1 03 00 12 e3  01 00 00 1a 17 00 a0 e3  |. ..............|
00000880  56 34 12 ef 00 20 0f e1  c0 20 82 e3 02 f0 21 e1  |V4... ... ....!.|
00000890  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000008a0  5c 41 9f e5 65 00 00 eb  57 0f 8f e2 4e 1c 90 e8  |\A..e...W...N...|
```

Comment: Does it boot when you reflash the original?  Can you tell anything by diffing the two images, or do they have too many arbitrary changes?  Have you considered trying to use CM's (or AOSP 5.1's) version of mkbootimg?

Comment: @ChrisStratton original - yes, boots fine. Hex dump shows some differences, but I'm not sure what to make out of it. Regarding version of mkbootimg -  I tried to build one from https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_system_core/mkbootimg, and it produced exactly the same binary with obviously same result

Comment: @galets great question and details! you put me on the right track to solve the problem :) Thank!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An obvious difference in your two hexdumps is the word stored starting 20 bytes into the image - 0x81200000 in yours vs 0x81700000 in the original - this stands out because 0x20 is a space while 0x70 is a printable "p" appearing in the right column.

Examining bootimg.h,

```
struct boot_img_hdr {
unsigned char magic[BOOT_MAGIC_SIZE];

unsigned kernel_size;  /* size in bytes */
unsigned kernel_addr;  /* physical load addr */

unsigned ramdisk_size; /* size in bytes */
unsigned ramdisk_addr; /* physical load addr */

unsigned second_size;  /* size in bytes */
unsigned second_addr;  /* physical load addr */
```

Where the first element is 8 bytes, it would appear that this is the ramdisk_addr, so your image is trying to load the ramdisk to a lower address than the original.

Further, both images try to load the kernel at 0x80208000, and the kernel is 0x00686988 in size, so loading the ramdisk at around 0x80700000 looks reasonable, while trying to load it at 0x80200000 is obviously broken as the ramdisk at a size of 0x000a1ec6 won't fit before a kernel starting 0x00008000 later, and would probably end up overwriting it.  I don't think this is a result of a different designed order of the two, but simply one of having the ramdisk offset be zero as a result of never being configured.

The source code seems to suggest there is a `--ramdisk_offset <base offset>` argument, so you might try that. You will have to figure out of the argument to this option should be an offset relative to a base, or an absolute, but examination of the documentation, or source, or a simple experiment and hexdump should sort that out.

This may not be the only issue (you can use some commandline options to diff to find the offsets of any other differences) - but it definitely looks to be at least one of the problems you will need to deal with.

Comment: using hex editor and changing this very offset produced runnable boot image. If you have any idea how to fix that without resorting to hex editor, I would very appreciate

Comment: It looks like this is one of the options that the usage message will display.  The hex editor was a good test - but even if this wasn't a command line option, you could fix it by modifying the program source code.

Comment: dumbass is my middle name. Adding `--ramdisk_offset 0x01500000 --tags_offset 0x00000100` took care of the problem

Comment: Glad you have a solution, but that doesn't at first glance seem like the original values.  Is you new kernel a lot bigger?

Comment: You are right, it doesn't seem like. However these are values that the unpack showed, and once the mkimage completes, the "20 81" becomes "70 81". There seem to be some calculations involved, which are probably clear from the code, but I haven't looked at it yet

Comment: @Chris Stratton you are the men!!!! 8 days with no progress. Thanks!!!!